# How to fetch from MySQL database “Hindi” हिन्दी text (Indian local language)

Tags: php, mysql

Database which stores my data is this:

[image]

Now I want to fetch that data and display on my php page, but when I'm trying to fetch data in my php code I'm getting text into the following formate

```
UID= ????/??????????/????/?????/?????/Test upgrade/1
UID= ????/??????????/??????/??????/??????????/159/1
UID= ????/??????????/??????/??????/??????????/190/1
UID= ????/??????????/??????/??????/??????????/194/1
UID= ????/??????????/??????/???????/?????? (??.)/730/1
UID= ????/??????????/??????/???????/?????? (??.)/742/1/1
UID= ????/??????????/??????/???????/?????? (??.)/732/1
UID= ????/??????????/??????/??????/??????/98/8/1
UID= ????/??????????/??????/??????/??????/48/10/1
```

Referring to this question I have changed my database charset to "utf8_unicode_ci", but Still not working. I have written following code to fetch the data

**datebase connection page**

```
<?php
    // Database configuration
    $dbHost = "localhost";
    $dbUsername = "user";
    $dbPassword = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    $dbName = "tutorialsssxxxxx";

    // Create database connection
    $db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

    // Check connection
    if ($db->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
    }
?>
```

**and index page**

```
<?php
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/header.php";
?><br>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="hi">
<head>
<title><?php echo $_GET['dta']; ?> Tutorials  Mrtutorials.net</title>
<link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Show loading overlay when ajax request starts
$( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
    $('.loading-overlay').show();
});
// Hide loading overlay when ajax request completes
$( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
    $('.loading-overlay').hide();
});
</script>


</head>
<body>      
<div class="content">
    <div class="dta"> <div class="list_item"><h2><?php echo $_GET['dta']; ?> Tutorials</h2></div>
<div class="post-wrapper">
    <div class="loading-overlay"><div class="overlay-content">Loading.....</div></div>
    <div id="posts_content">
    <?php
    //Include pagination class file
    include('Pagination.php');

    //Include database configuration file
    include('dbConfig.php');

    $limit = 10;

    //get number of rows
    $queryNum = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as postNum FROM posts");
    $resultNum = $queryNum->fetch_assoc();
    $rowCount = $resultNum['postNum'];

    //initialize pagination class
    $pagConfig = array('baseURL'=>'getData.php', 'totalRows'=>$rowCount, 'perPage'=>$limit, 'contentDiv'=>'posts_content');
    $pagination =  new Pagination($pagConfig);

    //get rows
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM posts Where type=$yyy ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $limit");

    if($query->num_rows > 0){ ?>
        <div class="posts_list">
        <?php
            while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
                $postID = $row['id'];
        ?>

<table width="" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0">
   <tr class="up"> 
     <td style="font-size: 45px; padding-left:5px; padding-right:5px"><?php echo $row["id"]; ?></td>
     <td valign="left" width="100%"><a href="/Ask/<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>/<?php echo $row["folder"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["title"]; ?></a> <br>  <?=$value['type']?></td>
   </tr>
 </table>

        <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <?php echo $pagination->createLinks(); ?>
    <?php } ?>
    </div>
</div></div>
</div>

</body>
</html><?php
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/footer.php";
?>
```

Comment: have you tried setting the character set of the mysqli connection with [set_charset](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php) ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use "set_charset"

Try this: (in your index.php)

```
//initialize pagination class
    $pagConfig = array('baseURL'=>'getData.php', 'totalRows'=>$rowCount, 'perPage'=>$limit, 'contentDiv'=>'posts_content');
    $pagination =  new Pagination($pagConfig);

    mysqli_set_charset( $db, 'utf8');

    //get rows
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM posts Where type=$yyy ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $limit");
```

To be precise, In your case you need to add this in code where you fetching the db:

```
mysqli_set_charset( $db, 'utf8');
```

Comment: IT SHOW  ERROR Initial character set: latin1 Current character set: utf8

Comment: Oh, Actually that is working fine, It's just a output of code exeucted.
I just showed how it will work, What you need to do is implementing the `mysqli_set_charset( $db, 'utf8');` in your code

Comment: Now I edited the answer to make more sense, try this, Also have a look at @phreakv6 answer.

Answer (score 1):

`mysqli_set_charset( $db, 'utf8');` will help you set `unicode` on the db connection. Now to show it in the page, you will still have to set the character encoding in html.

Remember to do this. Otherwise your page will still not show you the unicode characters.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing worked for me as per reply on stackoverflow.com, to display on web page, the Hindi Text from MySql through PHP.

The following code worked for me.  Please write your comments

```
enter code here

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM audio  WHERE AudioFor= 'Aarti' ORDER BY Name";
mysqli_set_charset( $conn, 'utf8');  **//  to get the hindi font/text displayed**
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) { ?>



    <table cellpadding="10">
<thead>
<tr align= "centre"><h3> Other Aartis  </h3></tr>
            <tr>

                 <th>Aarti Of</th>
                 <th>Wordings</th>                
                <th>Click to Listen</th>
                </tr>

<?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<tr><td >" . $row["Name"]."</td><td >" . $row["Wording"]. "</td><td >". ' <a href="' . $row["AudioPath"].'">Click To Listen </a>'. '</td></tr>';
    }
} //else {
   // echo "0 results";
//}
?>
```

Comment: How is this answer different from the one @Murali gave? In both cases seems like the missing statement to solve the problem is `mysqli_set_charset( $conn, 'utf8');`

Comment: in this coding, the connection is shown while in Murli answer it is shown as database.  In my answer, It is made very clear what the "$conn" is.  Murali's words: "To be precise, In your case you need to add this in code where you fetching the db:"

Answer (score 0):

After connecting to SQL Server and Database run the following query

```
msql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8")
```